# aws "serverless invoke local" fails to run when node_modules are on a parent folder

Tags: node-modules, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I have a serverless aws app within a context of many other ones. All of the node_modules are shared in a parent folder, and it works fine with deploys and invoke functions, not with invoke local. This is my structure:

```
main/
 - node_modules
 - serverless
     - app1
     - app2
         - serverless.yml
```

serverless.yml file settings:

```
package:
       include:
           - ../../node_modules/**
```

The problem is whenever I try to run `sls invoke local` I got a error messages due to package not found. So, the workaround is to `npm install --save` every package that is outside of my path.

If you have found a solution, not a workaround (like mine) please share :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was so obvious I wanted to delete my question, but I'll leave the answer here>

just go to the folder that contains your node_modules, you'll find a package.json there, and  run `npm install --save` for the new packages you need.

```
cd ../../
npm install --save missing_packages
```

your `serverless.yml` include should consider it when running local with no issues.
Violá!